# Test failed on different monitor selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am working at selenium webdriver with java. i have 2 screens in my office and i had set a fixed window dimension for chrome browser as

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1680, 1050));
```

when i execute code in office mean when i am connected with 2 screens every test case work fine both on laptop and second connected LED but when i remove second screen and work only at my laptop then test cases start failing.

**Note: above window size is greater than laptop screen but less than LED size**

I searched a lot to find a solution but failed.
Looking for solution to execute test case even when i am not connected with an external LED.
Help will be appreciated.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid hard coded value to check the window size first and then Assigned it based on screen size.

```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  System.out.println(driver.manage().window().getSize());
  driver.manage().window().setSize(driver.manage().window().getSize());
```

See if it helps.

Comment: I got your point but why hard coded size differ on both. Logically it should remain same for both.

Comment: I think it will be hard to manage in this case. Actually i want to make a same size for everyscreen.. If i will set according to Window size then may be there will be unclickable element and i need to scroll there to access

Comment: Because you are forcefully setting the window size which greater than the actual size on screen.

Comment: That's correct you need to scroll for sure.But what bothering you to scroll?

Comment: i am getting your point. But how will i manage elements. If a biger screen may be there will be no need to scroll if i will be on small screen than i need to scroll to acess the same element which was accessible on large screen. How can i manage this issue?

Comment: Confusion is that suppose i am maximizing window according to Window size and then elements location will be different for example on large screen no need to scroll while on small i need to scroll how will i differentiate this??

Answer (score -1):

In general when dealing with different screen resolution, we need to strict with resolution of all execution slaves. Say example,

> driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));

Or else we need to use JS scroll into view for all the commands to pass the cases for different resolution( but, not recommended considering performance).